# Constants in Doctrine 2 entities

Tags: php, constants, doctrine-orm

Suppose i'm having the following Doctrine 2 entity:

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 */
class User {

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     *
     * @var int
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(length=100)
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     *
     * @var int
     */
    protected $status;
}
```

The User can have several statuses, for example:  Pending, Active, Suspended. These statuses are needed throughout the code (services, repositories, etc.) and also in the UI layer (a User edit form would display them in a dropdown).

In order to avoid defining them in multiple places, what i've done so far was to use a class to hold them all (all the application's constants), and it looks somewhat like this:

```php
class App_Constants extends Zrzr_Constants
{

    protected static $_constants = array( 
        'users' => array( 
            'status' => array( 
                0 => 'Pending', 
                1 => 'Active',
                2 => 'Suspended' ) ) );

}
```

The base class (Zrzr_Constants) would offer some methods to retrieve them, and it looks like this:

```php
class Zrzr_Constants
{
    protected static $_constants = array();

    public static function getConstantValues( $key, $subkey )
    {
        // ...
    }

    public static function getConstantByName( $name )
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Common usage would be:

```php
// example of retrieval by constant name ... it would return an integer
$pendingStatus = App_Constants::getConstantByName( 'USERS.STATUS.PENDING' );

// example of retrieval for UI display purposes ... would return an array
$statuses = App_Constants::getConstantValues('users', 'status');
```

Of course this means that there are some limitations in that the constant labels cannot contain dots, but i can live with it.

Using Doctrine 2 and going the DDD way however, tells me that the 'status' field should be in fact a 'value object' (but Doctrine 2 does not support value objects yet), or at least that i should have the constants defined within the entity (using const).

My question is how would i do this so that i avoid constant redefinition for the UI layer? I need to have access to the constant by name (in the code) and to have all the possible values for such a field in the case of a UI dropdown (for example).

Comment: Your view is the only place that needs the names. The UI layer should do all the conversion between names and values; everywhere else should just use the integer value. It may be useful to add some methods to your entity like `isPending()`

Comment: @rojoca - When you say 'use the integer value' surely you don't mean something like: `if( $user->getStatus() == 2 ) ... `. The UI might not be the only other layer using these constants. What about these constants used in queries that don't go through the domain model (when employing some sort of CQS)?

Comment: No; in your example I think `if($user->isPending())` is better because it says exactly what it means. You can create constants like `User::STATUS_PENDING` in your domain model then use them in `App_Constants` e.g., `User::STATUS_PENDING => 'Pending'`. App_Constants is dependant on your domain whether you hardcode the values (as you do currently) or use class constants; you might as well use constants.

Comment: @rojoca Thanks for the suggestions. I looked into implementing a custom type (something like an enum), but as types are flyweights and don't hold state, i would need a new custom type for each such field. In the end without true Value Objects supported by Doctrine, i will need to implement it as you suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several years later and some more experience, what I consider to be the proper answer has changed. The initial question is about domain constants used in the UI layer, but the given example and the discussions actually refer to the following concepts: enums, enum maps and value objects. I did not have these concepts back then and the answers to my question did not provide them.

When you see or think of constants like `STATUS_PENDING`, `STATUS_ACTIVE`, `STATUS_SUSPENDED` you should be thinking of an enum. The standard PHP enum is insufficient so I like to use a third party library like [marc-mabe/php-enum](https://github.com/marc-mabe/php-enum). Here's how it would look like:

```
use MabeEnum\Enum;

/**
 * @method static UserStatus PENDING()
 * @method static UserStatus ACTIVE()
 * @method static UserStatus SUSPENDED()
 */
class UserStatus extends Enum
{
    const PENDING = 0;
    const ACTIVE = 1;
    const SUSPENDED = 2;
}
```

It's easy to turn this into a value object if you need to add functionality to it (I recommend doing it through composition, not inheritance). Coming back to the `User` entity, using the above enum the entity would end up like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 */
class User {

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     *
     * @var int
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(length=100)
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="user_status")
     *
     * @var UserStatus
     */
    protected $status;
}
```

Notice the column type is "user_status". To get this to work you need to define a custom Doctrine type and register it with Doctrine. Such a type would look like this:

```
/**
 * Field type mapping for the Doctrine Database Abstraction Layer (DBAL).
 *
 * UserStatus fields will be stored as an integer in the database and converted back to
 * the UserStatus value object when querying.
 */
class UserStatusType extends Type
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    const NAME = 'user_status';

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     *
     * @param array            $fieldDeclaration
     * @param AbstractPlatform $platform
     */
    public function getSQLDeclaration(array $fieldDeclaration, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        return $platform->getIntegerTypeDeclarationSQL($fieldDeclaration);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     *
     * @param string|null      $value
     * @param AbstractPlatform $platform
     */
    public function convertToPHPValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        if (empty($value)) {
            return null;
        }

        if ($value instanceof UserStatus) {
            return $value;
        }

        try {
            $status = UserStatus::get((int)$value);
        } catch (InvalidArgumentException $e) {
            throw ConversionException::conversionFailed($value, self::NAME);
        }

        return $status;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     *
     * @param UserStatus|null  $value
     * @param AbstractPlatform $platform
     */
    public function convertToDatabaseValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        if (empty($value)) {
            return null;
        }

        if ($value instanceof UserStatus) {
            return $value->getValue();
        }

        throw ConversionException::conversionFailed($value, self::NAME);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return self::NAME;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     *
     * @param AbstractPlatform $platform
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function requiresSQLCommentHint(AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Finally, when it comes to satisfying the needs of the user interface, you can end up using enum maps. Remember that the UI could need additional functionality such as multiple language support, so you cannot mash such concerns into the domain, hence the separation:

```
use MabeEnum\EnumMap;

class UserStatusMap extends EnumMap
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct(UserStatus::class);

        $this[UserStatus::PENDING] = ['name' => 'Pending'];
        $this[UserStatus::ACTIVE] = ['name' => 'Active'];
        $this[UserStatus::SUSPENDED] = ['name' => 'Suspended'];
    }
}
```

You can just add as many keys you want beside 'name'. In the UI you can make use of such a map like this:

```
// if you want to display the name when you know the value
echo (new UserStatusMap ())[UserStatus::PENDING]['name'];
// or
echo (new UserStatusMap ())[UserStatus::PENDING()]['name'];

// if you want to build a list for a select (value => name)
$list = (new UserStatusMap ())->toArray('name');
```

The `toArray` function is not available in MabeEnum\EnumMap but you can make your own:

```
use MabeEnum\EnumMap as BaseEnumMap;

class EnumMap extends BaseEnumMap
{
    /**
     * @param string|null $metadataKey
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($metadataKey = null)
    {
        $return = [];

        $flags = $this->getFlags();
        $this->setFlags(BaseEnumMap::KEY_AS_VALUE | BaseEnumMap::CURRENT_AS_DATA);

        if ($metadataKey) {
            foreach ($this as $key => $value) {
                $return[$key] = $value[$metadataKey];
            }
        } else {
            $return = iterator_to_array($this, true);
        }

        $this->setFlags($flags);

        return $return;
    }
}
```

To summarize:

1. Use an Enum to define a list of alternative values for a single field.
2. Create a Value Object which receives this Enum in the constructor if you want to add VO specific functionality to this field.
3. Use an Enum Map to serve the UI needs.

Comment: It's been over two years, do you still agree with everything in your answer?

Comment: Yes I do, I wouldn't change anything in my answer.

Answer (score 9):

I think, you can do it this way:

```
class User {
  const STATUS_PENDING = 'Pending';
  const STATUS_ACTIVE = 'Active';
  const STATUS_SUSPENDED = 'Suspended';

  public static function getStatusList() {
    return array(
                 self::STATUS_PENDING, 
                 self::STATUS_ACTIVE, 
                 self::STATUS_SUSPENDED
                );
  }

  public function getStatus() {...}

  public function setStatus($value) {...}

  public function isStatusPending() {...} //If you need it
}
```

On the UI layer, you can get text versions of your statuses using localization service (if status constants are numbers, UI layer can convert them to strings by adding prefix, for example user_status_0). In Symfony2 views you can use `trans` Twig filter for that to get text version of user status from `user` localization domain.

If your website is just in one language, then just User::STATUS_XXX will do fine, I think. I don't think you should overcomplicate the matter by creating a new class to hold statuses of the user.

If you will end up having many statuses or some other related things, I think you will have to create a separate entity for them.

Comment: I eventually ended up going this way in what domain constants are concerned, since it seems more natural in a DDD approach. I keep using the Constants class for other system wide constants that are not domain related.

Answer (score 4):

you can define your class as in the following example

```
class ContactResource
{
   const TYPE_PHONE = 1;
   const TYPE_EMAIL = 2;
   const TYPE_BIRTDAY = 3;
   const TYPE_ADDRESS = 4;
   const TYPE_OTHER = 5;
   const TYPE_SKYPE = 6;
   const TYPE_LINKEDIN = 7;
   const TYPE_MEETUP = 8;
   const TYPE_TELEGRAM = 9;
   const TYPE_INSTAGRAM = 10;
   const TYPE_TWITTER = 11;

   public static $resourceType = array(
       ContactResource::TYPE_PHONE => "Phone",
       ContactResource::TYPE_EMAIL => "Email",
       ContactResource::TYPE_BIRTDAY => "Birtday",
       ContactResource::TYPE_ADDRESS => "Address",
       ContactResource::TYPE_OTHER => "Other",
       ContactResource::TYPE_SKYPE => "Skype",
       ContactResource::TYPE_LINKEDIN => "LinkedIn",
       ContactResource::TYPE_MEETUP => "Meetup",
       ContactResource::TYPE_TELEGRAM => "Telegram",
       ContactResource::TYPE_INSTAGRAM => "Instagram",
       ContactResource::TYPE_TWITTER => "Twitter",
   );

   /**
   * @var integer
   *
   * @ORM\Column(type="integer", length=2)
   *
   */
   private $type;


   public function __toString()
   {
      return (string)$this->getType();
   }

   public function getType()
   {
      if (!is_null($this->type)) {
          return self::$resourceType[$this->type];
      } else {
          return null;
      }
   }

   public static function getTypeList() {
      return self::$resourceType;
   }

}
```

If you need to get the type in Twig

```
{{ entity.type }}
```

For the list of choices

```
ContactResource::getTypeList()
```

Hope works for you!

Comment: How is this different from what Vladislav's answer?

Comment: Vladislav's answer is right, but it's important to define the toString method and also de getters and setters to use it.

I only want to complement the response :)

Comment: I don't follow when is $type defined? So then, how do you get the resourceType associated with your constant value? thanks.